How to create column and rows using select statement CTE?
I'm able to create the table using CTE with select statement like below but it's not behaving like I want.
with sorting(item_code, index) as (
 select (10001, 1), (10002, 2)
)
select * from sorting

Table result :
item_code|index    |
---------+---------+
(10001,1)|(10002,2)|

Basically I want to create table with value like this :
item_code | index
10001     | 1
10002     | 2

How could I do that using SQL?

What purpose has the CTE? You can simply write SELECT 10001 as item_code, 1 as "index" union all select 10002,2. Or what is your real question?

You can switch select over to values keyword and get what you want. This is a postgres feature called "constants table" dbfiddle here

I want to reference this table latter on, since this table is dynamic and might only have 3 - 10 values inside it. I figure I want to use CTE since I can reference it on JOIN

This is most probably what you want using the values clause:
demo at db<>fiddle
with sorting(item_code, index)as(values
  (10001, 1)
 ,(10002, 2) )
select * from sorting;




item_code
index




10001
1


10002
2




you can try this:
with sorting(item_code, index) as (
    select 10001 as item_code, 1 as index
    union all
    select 10002 as item_code, 2 as index
)
select * from sorting

